# JQuery/Ajax Post returned data and IF function

Tags: jquery, ajax, if-statement

This is whats in my main.js file:

```
$("#login-form").submit(
        function() {

            $("#message").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').html(
                    '<img src="public/images/loading.gif" />Validating....').fadeIn(1000);

            $.post("login/run", {
                username : $('#username').val(),
                password : $('#password').val()
            }, function(data) {
                if (data == 'yes') {
                    // add message and change the class of the box and start
                    // fading
                    $("#message").fadeTo(
                            200,
                            0.1,
                            function() // start fading the messagebox
                            {

                                $(this).html('Logging In...').addClass(
                                        'messageboxok').fadeTo(900, 1,
                                        function() {
                                            // redirect to secure page
                                            document.location = 'secure.php';
                                        });
                            });

                } else {
                    alert(data);
                    $("#message").fadeTo(
                            200,
                            0.1,
                            function() // start fading the messagebox
                            {


                                    // add message and change the class of the
                                    // box and start fading
                                    $(this).html('Your username or password is incorrect')
                                            .addClass('messageboxerror')
                                            .fadeTo(900, 1);


                            });
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
);
```

this is the function it refers to (currently set to always echo yes so as to force a positive result)

```
public function run() {
    echo 'yes';
}
```

The problem I'm having is when I do the alert(data), the alert shows that the output I'm getting is correct, however the IF function is only doing the ELSE part regardless that the data is yes.

The other confusing part is that this code worked fine before I went to bed last night - just now it doesn't.

Is there a problem in my syntax anywhere?

---

### Edit 1

Modified it by:
added **, 'json'** to the end of the $.post area, and added **json_encode** to the echo

main.js to:

```
//login form ajax
$("#login-form").submit(
        function() {

            $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').html(
                    '<img src="public/images/loading.gif" />Validating....').fadeIn(1000);

            $.post("login/run", {
                username : $('#username').val(),
                password : $('#password').val()
            }, function(data) {
                if (data == 'yes') {
                    // add message and change the class of the box and start
                    // fading
                    $("#msgbox").fadeTo(
                            200,
                            0.1,
                            function() // start fading the messagebox
                            {

                                $(this).html('Logging In...').addClass(
                                        'messageboxok').fadeTo(900, 1,
                                        function() {
                                            // redirect to secure page
                                            document.location = 'secure.php';
                                        });
                            });

                } else {
                    alert(data);
                    $("#msgbox").fadeTo(
                            200,
                            0.1,
                            function() // start fading the messagebox
                            {


                                    // add message and change the class of the
                                    // box and start fading
                                    $(this).html('Your username or password is incorrect')
                                            .addClass('messageboxerror')
                                            .fadeTo(900, 1);


                            });
                }
            }, 'json');
            return false;
        });
//end login form ajax
```

and the function to:

```
public function run() {
        echo json_encode('yes');

}
```

---

### Edit 2

Changed to $.ajax, made the function return a JSON encoded array

main.js:

```
$("#login-form").submit(
        function() {

            $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').html(
                    '<img src="public/images/loading.gif" />Validating....').fadeIn(1000);


            $.ajax({
                url: 'login/run',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    username : $('#username').val(),
                    password : $('#password').val()
                },
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data.result);


                    if (data.result == 'yes') {
                        // add message and change the class of the box and start
                        // fading
                        $("#msgbox").fadeTo(
                                200,
                                0.1,
                                function() // start fading the messagebox
                                {

                                    $(this).html('Logging In...').addClass(
                                            'messageboxok').fadeTo(900, 1,
                                            function() {
                                                // redirect to secure page
                                                document.location = 'secure.php';
                                            });
                                });

                    } else {
                        alert(data);
                        $("#msgbox").fadeTo(
                                200,
                                0.1,
                                function() // start fading the messagebox
                                {


                                        // add message and change the class of the
                                        // box and start fading
                                        $(this).html('Your username or password is incorrect')
                                                .addClass('messageboxerror')
                                                .fadeTo(900, 1);


                                });
                    }



                    //return false; 
                }
            });


            return false;
        });
```

function:

```
public function run() {
    $result = array('result' => 'yes');
    echo json_encode($result);  
}
```

Comment: i suggest you change your `$.post` for `$.ajax({...});` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Try `alert( data.length )`. If it's not 3, you might have a space or newline character there.

Comment: @JasonP i belive you have a better way to handle callbacks, beforeSend, complete, errors... having a complete ajax config. I prefer using like this, its easy to debug and other things. Not that $.post{} its wrong. I just give my opinion :)

Comment: If you need the extra configuration, sure. Complete and errors can be handled with any ajax shorthand method now using `done()`, `always()`, and `fail()`.

Comment: alert(data.length) returns 5, is $.ajax a better way to do it?

Comment: @user1842842 Only if you need the extra configuration options, which I don't think you do in this case. But you've established now that your return value contains whitespace. You might be better off changing your response type to JSON to prevent this sort of issue.

Comment: @JasonP thanks, it works now - I put my edits in my original post at the bottom, have I correctly changed the response type to JSON ?

Comment: I'm not sure what server-side language that is, but it would seem to me that you need a key and a value for the json response, not just a value. Do a little research on how to return a json response from whatever language you're using.

Comment: sorry - I'm using php

Comment: updated my original code with what I've done now, is that correct? I'm going to carry on looking through other sources to see if thats correct